# Flat file Comparison Tool

Tags: java, file, text, comparison, large-data

**Flatfile1.txt**

```
HDR06112016FLATFILE     TXT  
CLM12345     ABCDEF....  
DTL12345     100A00....  
DTL12345     200B00....  
CLM54321     ABCDEF....  
DTL54321     100C00....  
DTL54321     200D00....
```

**Flatfile2.txt**

```
HDR06112016FLATFILE     TXT  
CLM54321     FEDCBA....  
DTL54321     100C00....  
DTL54321     200D00....  
CLM12345     ABCDEF....  
DTL12345     100A00....  
DTL12345     200B00....
```

**Mapping for both file will be same:**

```
Header:  
Field       StartPosition       EndPos       Length   
Identifier       1                 3           3  
Date             4                12           8  
and so on
```

Clm:

```
Field       StartPosition       EndPos       Length   
Identifier       1                 3           3  
Key              4                12           8  
Data            13                19           6  
and so on
```

Dtl:

```
Field       StartPosition       EndPos       Length   
Identifier       1                 3           3  
Key              4                12           8  
and so on
```

This is a sample file and may size upto 500mb and about 50 fields.  I will need to compare the two files based on their mapping. The file format is - one header and claim data(12345) in one line and its detail data can be more than one. These claims can be present randomly in the other file.Its not line to line mapping. Detail data ordering will be same in both the files.

**Desired output :**

```
For Key 54321 , Data(pos 13:19) is not same.
```

Would you please help me in comparing the two files? Will it be feasible in Java since the file size will be huge?.

Comment: Please visit the [help] and read [ask].  Have you written any code?  Are you asking us to write your code for you?  Sorry, but StackOverflow doesn't work that way.  You are expected to attempt a solution and ask a specific question when you encounter difficulties.  StackOverflow is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

Java would work fine.  You don't need to have the files entirely in memory; you can open them both and read from both incrementally, comparing as you go along.